# Installing LAPACK to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, lapack

I seem to have problem with installing LAPACK library to my Visual Studio 2015 (C++, Windows 10).

I have downloaded precompiled libraries from here: https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#libraries

I have also written "liblapack.lib" and "libblas.lib" to **Project properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies** and written *C:\Documents\LAPACK* (which is where libraries are located) to **Project properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories**. I still get error

> LNK1104 cannot open file 'liblapack.lib'

Changing "liblapack.lib" to "LAPACK.lib" or "LAPACKd.lib" didn't work anyway
Any help please?

Comment: Did you change them for the correct configuration, i.e. Debug/Release, x86/x64?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the path `C:\Documents\LAPACK` is correct? Do you really have a `Documents` folder in your `C:\ ` root directory? My gut feeling tells me you put it in your profile's documents folder, not in the root path - in this case try `$(USERPROFILE)\Documents\LAPACK` as additional library directory (or in case my memory is wrong and it doesn't work, try `%userprofile%\Documents\LAPACK` as well)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example visual studio 2015 solution that builds a simple main.cpp using the LAPACK libraries and dlls: https://bitbucket.org/aperezrathke/vs-lapack

Basically, the VS solution adds a Post-Build Event to copy the relevant dlls into your exe folder (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7dhf0ty.aspx)

To see this, open the solution file and navigate to the **Project** > **Properties** page (Alt+F7). Then navigate to **Configuration Properties** > **Build Events** > **Post-Build Event**.

In the *Command Line* field, there is:

`xcopy "$(SolutionDir)Binaries" "$(TargetDir)" /Y`

Assuming the necessary LAPACK dlls are in `$(SolutionDir)Binaries`, then this will copy the dlls to the executable folder every time the build is successful.

If instead you don't want to copy the dlls every time, then the folder containing the dlls should be added to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It might be enough to use clapack for your purposes. See all details here: http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/clapack/index.html

1. install msvc 2015, I used community edition
2. install cmake https://cmake.org/files/v3.6/cmake-3.6.1-win64-x64.msi
3. download http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/clapack/clapack-3.2.1-CMAKE.tgz
4. run cmake gui, point to folder with unzipped tgz, set some other folder as output. generate solution, open it in msvc, build all projects (takes few minutes)
5. use this sample project for testing http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/clapack/CLAPACK-EXAMPLE.zip (put your built .libs to /lib folder)